# Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 14155776 values, but the requested shape has 262144

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I am trying to use ELMO embedding to train my Network with LSTM but i have a problem with the shape of the tensor
**y-train with shape (67689, 5) encoded with 1 hot vector (the output is 5 classes)
x-train with shape (67689,) is text formate**
this the code:

```
from  tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense
from  tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import  tensorflow.keras.backend as K

batch_size=32
sequence_length=58
def ElmoEmbedding(x):
    return elmo_model(inputs={
                            "tokens": tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)),
                            "sequence_len": tf.constant(batch_size*[sequence_length])
                      },
                      signature="tokens",
                      as_dict=True)["elmo"]

input_text = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding = Lambda(ELMoEmbedding, output_shape=(58,1024,))(input_text)
reshape_2 = Reshape((1024, 1,))(embedding)
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=100, recurrent_activation='relu', return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(reshape_2)
reshape_3 = Reshape(( 5,))(lstm)
pred = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(reshape_3)
model = Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
with tf.Session() as session:
    K.set_session(session)
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  
    session.run(tf.tables_initializer())


   
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=256,validation_split = 0.2, shuffle=True)
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, verbose=False)
    print("Training Accuracy: {:.4f}".format(accuracy))
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=False)
    print("Testing Accuracy:  {:.4f}".format(accuracy))
```

and I got this error

> InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) Invalid argument:
> Input to reshape is a tensor with 52428800 values, but the requested
> shape has 1280     [[{{node reshape_45/Reshape}}]]
> [[loss_49/mul/_847]]   (1) Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a
> tensor with 52428800 values, but the requested shape has 1280
> [[{{node reshape_45/Reshape}}]] 0 successful operations. 0 derived
> errors ignored.